# Does the Facebook's live stream social plugin allow tag filtering?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'd like to build a feature similar to Envolve's chat plugin on my site that would allow users to chat (no webcams) around specific topics, using Facebook Connect. Users must also be able to see present users that are not connected to them so the XMPP option is out. The live stream social plugin isn't sufficient because there doesn't seem to be tag filtering so having 5 different chats about 5 different topics for instance doesn't seem viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you specify an xid... "If you have multiple live stream boxes on the same page, specify a unique `xid` for each."
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/

Comment: Thanks I was actually going to edit the question to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

We're adding jabber support soon so you'll be able to chat with Facebook users via your site. Please let us know what else your looking for. support[at]envolve.com

- James (Founder @ Envolve)

Comment: Hi James. I follow you on Twitter so when you do make sure to post it there.